# Salting Passwords

Tags: hash, salt

I could really use some clarification as to how using a random salt protects against rainbow table attacks.  It just isn't clicking for me.

Suppose there is a dumb application that requires passwords to be exactly five characters or less, and that salts those passswords with a nine-character random salt.  If I have a rainbow table that has precomputed hashes of all character combinations 14 characters or less, how does the random salt provide any additional security?  In this case won't the hashed value of the random salt + password combo. be present in the rainbow table?

I have read multiple places that using a salt would force the cracker to generate an entirely new rainbow table; similarly, a random per-password salt would require a new rainbow table for each salt. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone truly has a rainbow table containing the hash of all possible character combinations, then no, salting is of no help.  But even assuming just `A-z`, `a-z`, `0-9` as valid characters, that's 62<sup>14</sup> = 1.2x10<sup>25</sup> 14-character passwords.  So that's 170 billion petabytes of storage required.

Given that that's not feasible, the attacker must have a **much** smaller table, containing only the most likely character strings (e.g. all the words in a dictionary, intermingled with numbers, etc.).  If you add a salt, then this table becomes useless.  If the salt is fixed (and known), then the attacker could recompute a new table.  But if each password has a different salt, then that won't work either.

Comment: Thank you.  So a key consideration of using a salt is salt length?  That is, a salt of one character is of dubios value, but a salt of 32 characters adds excellent security?

Comment: @user101570: I suppose so.  But even a single character increases the combinations by a factor of 62.  It doesn't take many characters before it becomes completely infeasible for the attacker to store all combinations.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so, what you are saying is that you are protecting other users from the potential breaking into of one account, as well? It's protecting other by making each unique?

Answer (score 1):

One of the faster yet to some extent effective ways to see what a password is by creating a hash on all words in a dictionary, for example. People who try to crack passwords know what they're looking for and due to limited computing speeds they narrow their search down to often used passwords. By using a salt these often used words will never truly be used as a password.

Comment: I understand how it offers some protectio against dictionary attacks.  But what about a rainbow table that contains all hashes for all possible character combos up to a certain number of characters.  How does salting help in this case?